# Why %24 is showing in URL

Tags: get

Why %24 is showing in URL
http://localhost/sdbms/addAttendance.php?%24att_nu_status+1=A&%24att_nu_status+2=A&att_update_button=Updated

And i am unable to get values of att_nu_status :(
it the the names of a text boxes generated by for loop on $i as
" name="$att_nu_status ">

I wanted to get the updated value $att_candidate_status is showing in the text box for default

Comment: Please tag with the language you are working in. It appears PHP is involved but we need to know what language you are generating that URL in. It looks like you are accidentally adding your variable name to the URL instead of it's value. %24 is a urlencoded "$"

Answer (score 11):

When you send a request over http some of the special characters are replaced with some other characters this is known as HTTP URL encoding and at the server side it is then again decoded. %24 is the Url encoded character for $ . 
Check if the request that you are doing is correct as in the url I can see att_nu_status+1=A att_nu_status+2=A.