# Unable to edit data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-blade

Using Laravel, I'm trying to change data about an object. The "**Edit**" button works, but when I want to save the changes, it says: "*404
NOT FOUND*" , the link also looks like:

> http://***/categories/%24category/edit_token=KKamIVgz6HFOrKa0jZBwxnBdui9bP0KPXB4kD4Uf&_method=PUT&name=name

.
What should I do?

**body** *(location of transition to the edit tab)*:

```
<x-base-layout>
    
    <div class="space-x-4">
        <x-jet-nav-link href="/categories">
            Index
        </x-jet-nav-link>
    
        <x-jet-nav-link href="/categories/create">
            Create
        </x-jet-nav-link>
    </div>
        
    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="mx-auto max-w-7x1 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="overflow-hidden shadow-x1 sm:rounded-lg">
                <table class="w-full">
                    <thead class="font-bold bg-dark-200">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="px-2 py-3 text-xs tracking-wider text-left uppercase"></th>

                            <th class="px-2 py-3 text-xs tracking-wider text-left uppercase">
                                Id
                            </th>

                            <th class="px-2 py-3 text-xs tracking-wider text-left uppercase">
                                Name
                            </th>

                            <th class="px-2 py-3 text-xs tracking-wider text-left uppercase">
                                Sub Categories
                            </th>

                            <th class="px-2 py-3 text-xs tracking-wider text-left uppercase">
                                Created Date
                            </th>

                            <th class="px-2 py-3 text-xs tracking-wider text-left uppercase">
                                Updated Date
                            </th>

                            <th class="px-2 py-3 text-xs tracking-wider text-left uppercase">
                                Actions
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody class="text-xs bg-dark-300">
                        @foreach ($categories as $category)
                        <tr>
                            <td class="px-2 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-white-600" style="color: black; font-weight: 500;">
                            </td>

                            <td class="px-2 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-white-600" style="color: black; font-weight: 500;">
                                {{ $category->id }}
                            </td>

                            <td class="px-2 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-white-600" style="color: black; font-weight: 500;">
                                {{ $category->name }}
                            </td>

                            <td class="px-2 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-white-600" style="color: black; font-weight: 500;">
                                <ul class="flex">
                                    @foreach ($category->subCategories as $subCategory)
                                    <li class="px-2">{{ $subCategory->name }}, </li>
                                        
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            </td>

                            <td class="px-2 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-white-600" style="color: black; font-weight: 500;">
                                {{ $category->created_at->format('m/d/y')}}
                            </td>

                            <td class="px-2 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-white-600" style="color: black; font-weight: 500;">
                                {{ $category->updated_at->format('m/d/y') }}
                            </td>

                            <td class="px-2 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500 whitespace-nowrap">
{{-- EDIT --}}
                                <div class="flex justify-start space-x-1">
                                    <a href=" {{ route('categories.edit', $category) }} " class="p-1 border-2 border-white-500 rounded-md">
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-500">
                                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15.232 5.232l3.536 3.536m-2.036-5.036a2.5 2.5 0 113.536 3.536L6.5 21.036H3v-3.572L16.732 3.732z" />
                                        </svg>
                                    </a>
                                
{{-- DELETE --}}
                                    <form action="{{ route('categories.destroy', '$category') }}" method="POST">
                                        @csrf
                                        @method("Delete")
                                        <button type="submit" class="p-1 border-2 border-primary rounded-md">
                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"     stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-red-500">
                                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M19    7l-.867 12.142A2 2 0 0116.138 21H7.862a2 2 0 01-1.995-1.858L5 7m5  4v6m4-6v6m1-10V4a1 1 0 00-1-1h-4a1 1 0 00-1 1v3M4 7h16" />
                                            </svg>
                                        </button>
                                    </form>

                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</x-base-layout>
```

**CategoryController.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\StoreCategoryRequest;
use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::with('subCategories')->whereNull('parent_id')->get();
        return view('dashboard.categories.index', compact('categories'));
        // return "Hello world!";
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $categories = Category::with('subCategories')->whereNull('parent_id')->get();
        return view('dashboard.categories.create', compact('categories'));  
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(StoreCategoryRequest $request)
    {
        $category               = new Category;
        $category->name         = $request->name;
        $category->parent_id    = $request->parent_id;
        $category->slug         = Str::slug($request->name);
        $category->save();

        return redirect()->route('categories.index')->with('success', 'Category successfully created');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Category  $category
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Request $request, Category $category){
        return redirect()->route('dashboard.categories.update');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Category  $category
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Category $category)
    {
        $categories = Category::with('subCategories')->whereNull('parent_id')->get();
        return view('dashboard.categories.edit', compact('category', 'categories'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Category  $category
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Category $category)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
           'name' => ['required', 'unique:categories'],
           'parent_id' => ['sometimes', 'nullable'] 
        ]);

        $category->name = $request->name;
        $category->slug = Str::slug($request->name);
        $category->save();

        return redirect()->route('categories.index')->with('success', 'Category succesfully updated!');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Category  $category
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Category $category)
    {
        $category->delete();

        return redirect()->route('categories.index')->with("success", 'Category succesfully deleted!');
    }
}
```

**edit view**:

```
<x-base-layout>
    <div class="space-x-4">
        <x-jet-nav-link href="/categories">
            Index
        </x-jet-nav-link>
    
        <x-jet-nav-link href="/categories/create">
            Create
        </x-jet-nav-link>
    </div>

    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-4x1 mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-6">
            <div class="overflow-hidden bg-dark-300 shadow-x1 sm:rounded-lg">

                <div class="p-4">
                    <form action="{{ route('categories.edit', '$category') }}" method="GET">
                        @csrf
                        @method('PUT')

                        <div>
                            <x-jet-label for="name" class="text-white-600" value="{{ __('Name') }}" />
                            <x-jet-input id="name" class="block mt-1 w-full text-dark bg-dark-200 border-white-200" type="text" name="name" :value="old('name')" required autofocus autocomplete="name" />
                            <span class="text-xs text-white-300">Maximum 80 character</span>
                            <x-jet-input-error for="name" class="mt-2" />
                        </div>

                        <x-jet-button class="ml-4 mt-12">
                            {{ __('Update') }}
                        </x-jet-button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-base-layout>
```

**Route.php**:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
Route::resource('categories', CategoryController::class)->middleware("auth");

require __DIR__ . '/auth.php';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems.  First up, the edit form uses:

```
<form action="{{ route('categories.edit', '$category') }}" method="GET">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
```

But as with any route which *changes* data, it should be POST:

```
<form action="{{ route('categories.edit', '$category') }}" method="POST">
```

Next, the URL you land on includes `%24`:

> http://***/categories/%24category...

[That's a URL-encoded `$`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30957385/why-24-is-showing-in-url/30957469).  That's because PHP does not interpolate variables in single quotes - `'$category'` winds up in your URL *exactly* like that: `http://***/categories/$category/...`.  You need to use double quotes around variables if you want the variable to be interpolated: `"$category"`.

However!  You don't actually want any quotes there, as what you have is not [the documented way](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes) to pass a parameter to a named route.  You should use:

```
<form action="{{ route('categories.edit', ['category' => $category]) }}" method="POST">
```

Also, an unrelated problem, on the page you've described as the `body`, you have stray whitespace in your edit links:

```
<a href=" {{ route('categories.edit', $category) }} "
//       ^.........................................^ --- remove those spaces
```

I'm surprised those links work, those spaces should be removed.